# I'm trying to let users pick mobile site or desktop site through user agent

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

How should i direct user to a desktop site via mobile?  I've read everything about sessions and javascript.  Is there a way to take a page out of google and change the user agent for a user and not cookie them,  javascript, or monitor the session?

This is my current check:

```
Protected Sub Page_PreInit(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.PreInit
        If Request.Browser.IsMobileDevice Then
        MasterPageFile = "~/Mobile.Master"
    End If
End Sub
```

I'm current trying to do this in vb, but it is changing my site to desktop for all users.  I can't figure out a temp hack (fix) for the current user.  The above code is on my default.aspx page.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This should be done on the client, not server-side. And Feature detection is preferred way to UserAgent. Take a look at http://modernizr.com/